# which version of ucdetector is compatible with easy Eclipse with fedora operating system

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using the easy eclipse on fedora Linux system. I have to configure the ucdetector with easy eclipse. which version of ucdetector is suitable with this.Please tell me the solution.

Thanks in advance..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org) version 1.4.0 is for eclipse versions: >=3.3

Looking at www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/index.html this version seems to be ok for Easyeclipse >= 1.3.1